# Django Celery Error

Tags: django, celery

I'm been trying to schedule a task for celery to do at the background but I keep encountering issues.

**Quick reference on what I've done so far**

I installed `celery` and `django-celery` via `easy_install`, added to `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
'djcelery',
'kombu.transport.django',
```

imported the following and ran syncdb:

```
 import djcelery
 djcelery.setup_loader()
 BROKER_URL = "django://"
```

---

The task I'm trying to run in the background is password reset. So when a user forget his password , I want to make the sending email task run in the background so what I done is
I moved my forgot_password function from `views.py` into `tasks.py` so it can run.

My `tasks.py`:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.views import password_reset
 from django.shortcuts import render
 from celery.decorators import task

 @task()
 def forgot_password(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         return password_reset(request,
             from_email=request.POST.get('email'))
     else:
         return render(request, 'forgot_password.html')
```

Their nothing in `views.py` now.

The problem is even though, I can send email if I lose my password. I'm not sure if it's running in the background. What I did to check is was:

```
 manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info
```

but I get an error: `KeyError: 'processName'`:

```
 C:\o\17\mysite>manage.py celery worker --loglevel=info

  -------------- celery@gg-PC v3.0.19 (Chiastic Slide)
 ---- **** -----
 --- * ***  * -- Windows-Vista-6.0.6001-SP1
 -- * - **** ---
 - ** ---------- [config]
 - ** ---------- .> broker:      django://localhost//
 - ** ---------- .> app:         default:0x319c930 (djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader
 )
 - ** ---------- .> concurrency: 2 (processes)
 - *** --- * --- .> events:      OFF (enable -E to monitor this worker)
 -- ******* ----
 --- ***** ----- [queues]
  -------------- .> celery:      exchange:celery(direct) binding:celery


 [Tasks]
   . accounts.tasks.forgot_password

 [2013-05-15 17:49:45,279: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\dja
 ngo_celery-3.0.17-py2.6.egg\djcelery\loaders.py:133: UserWarning: Using settings
 .DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never use this setting in production environments
 !
   warnings.warn('Using settings.DEBUG leads to a memory leak, never '
 [2013-05-15 17:49:45,292: WARNING/MainProcess] celery@gg-PC ready.
 [2013-05-15 17:49:45,292: INFO/MainProcess] consumer: Connected to django://loca
 lhost//.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python26\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 754, in emit
     msg = self.format(record)
   File "C:\Python26\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 637, in format
     return fmt.format(record)
   File "C:\Python26\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 428, in format
     s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
 KeyError: 'processName'
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python26\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 754, in emit
     msg = self.format(record)
   File "C:\Python26\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 637, in format
     return fmt.format(record)
   File "C:\Python26\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 428, in format
     s = self._fmt % record.__dict__
 KeyError: 'processName'
```

Can someone please kindly help me by tell me if forget password is configured probably to send emails in the background and why do I get this error `KeyError: 'processName'`?

Comment: Try manage.py celeryd --loglevel=info

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is a simple way of sending emails using celery:

[django-celery-email](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery-email)

Second, your task is wrong. Task is a background job, not view. It should perform the final operation. In your case this is sending email

Comment: I did put the task in task.py